# Trying to create a mongodb schema for an app, but wondering do I just make 3 collections?

Tags: mongodb

Basically, I have right now a postgreSQL database having the following:

`Family` which contains `family_id, family_name, and f_url`

`Member` which contains `member_id, family_id, associations` where associations is a comma separated field where user adds up to 10 associations to different families.

Finally, members can add posts to their family, so `Data` which contains `id, title, message, image_link`.

I am trying to learn mongodb and I am wondering how the h**k to proceed for this simple thing.  Do I just make 3 collections having the same set up or is there another way to do this?

I have made 3 collections having the same set up, but then is that correct?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideal will be to design in a way so that you can deal with everything within just one json object. That will guarantee atomicity. No transactions needed.

In Mongo DB, the database is design by considering following factors.

- How the data will be used.
- Which data is read only, which we need to write again and again.
  What data needs to be grouped together.
- The single most important factor in designing your application schema
  within Mongo DB is to match the data access patterns of your
  application.
- The database design in Mongo DB is more like a collection of objects
  in software design world.
- Another design tip is, if you are doing it like a relation db, you
  are doing something wrong.

Comment: Thank you sir.  When I have computer access again I will post again and in the mean while time I will try to follow your advise.